# ifstream not working with dirent.h

Tags: c++, file

I'm testing optimizations for dijkstra algorithm and to make it easier to open files I used "dirent.h" to get all the test files in the running path and then ifstream to open this file.
the `readDirec` method reads all the files in the directory and ignores folder and puts those files names in a vector called files.

```c++
void selectDirec(){
    files.clear();
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    if ((dir = opendir (".")) != NULL) {
      while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
        if(opendir(ent->d_name) == NULL){
            files.push_back(ent->d_name);
        }
      }
      closedir (dir);
    } else {
      cout<<"directory error"<<endl;
    }
}
```

after that I uses a function called selectFile which assigns the name of the file the user chooses to a variable called fileName.

```c++
void selectFile(){
    selectDirec();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < files.size() ; i++){
        cout<<i+1<<" : "<<files[i]<<endl;
    }
    int choice = 0;

    do{
        cout<<"enter file number"<<endl;
        cin>>choice;
    }while(choice > files.size());
    choice--;
    fileName = files[choice];
    cout<<fileName<<":"<<endl;
}
```

after that I enter my readGraph function which opens the file and continue graph operations

```c++
void readGraph(){
    ifstream ifile; ifile.open(fileName);
    if(!ifile.is_open()){
        cout<<"no file with the name specified"<<endl;
        eflag = true;
        return;
    }
  ...
  ...
}
```

initialization:

```c++
vector<char *> files;
char * fileName ;
```

now I have those 5 files to test which I got from here http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/44sp/:

tinyEWD.txt contains 8 vertices and 15 edges [140B]
mediumEWD.txt contains 250 vertices and 2,546 edges[40KB]
1000EWG.txt contains 1,000 vertices and 16,866 edges[313KB]
10000EWG.txt contains 10,000 vertices and 123,462 edges[2.4MB]
NYC.txt . contains 264346 vertices and 733846 edges[12.7MB].

but there's a weird problem with those 3 files:
'mediumEWD' , '10000EWD.txt' , 'NYC.txt'

when I choose any of them the code shows me "no file with the name specified" that in the else statement in `readGraph`.

but when I enter their name manually and comment `selectDirec` and `selectFile` the program opens them successfully.

P.S. I checked the file name and spacing and everything.
P.S.2 currently running this code on ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure that "filename" contains correct name of file when you entering to readGraph() ?

Comment: Why do I suspect `files` is a `std::vector<char*>`?

Comment: @Sandro yes I printed it in readGraph and it prints the exact file name.

Comment: well the whole main file has those 3 function and the fourth is the regular int main . also there aren't no other global variable named files in the file. and the print statement shows that the file is the same as I chose.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(opendir(ent->d_name) == NULL){
    files.push_back(ent->d_name);
}
```

What is `files`? I suspect that you are using a `std::vector<const char *>`, or something along the same lines.

This won't work. `d_name` is a part of the dirent structure. Immediately afterwards, and certainly after the `closedir()`, that pointer is no longer valid, and points to deallocated memory.

Looks to me like you then proceed and attempt to use the no-longer valid pointer as the filename parameter to `std::ifstream`.

You should use a `std::vector<std::string>` to store the filenames, and use the `c_str()` member function to extract a pointer to a C-style string, for the `open`() call.

You can't be using a vector of `std::string`s here, this must be a vector of raw character pointers. That's because you're assigning one of its values to `fileName`, whatever it is, and then passing it directly to `open()` without using `c_str()`. So it can't be a vector of strings.

Comment: thanks for the answer. the initialization is put right after the functions code. your answer is valid in windows as I get a vector of elements pointing to the same thing. but in ubuntu the function takes the file name right as you see that the print operation goes after closedir and it prints the file name right.

Comment: "Undefined behavior" means just that: undefined. Just because one part of your programs works as intended, doesn't mean that everything else will. At the time the print operation happens, each char * pointer could still point to memory which formerly stored the filename, but by the time you try to open the file, it's been clobbered or overwritten. Does your vector contain char pointers or not. If it is, then it's broken and that's your problem. Just because your code continues to work somewhat, for a little while, doesn't mean that it's not broken.